# Can I create Release pipeline (CD) in Azure DevOps directly using YAML?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I need to create a release pipeline (CD) without creating a CI pipeline. I will use artifacts from GitHub. Can I create the CD using YAML or it is like I need to create CI with YAML and CD can not be created directly using YAML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create Release classic pipeline using YAML. Your only option is the editor. But YAML has something different (which in the future can replace Release pipelines - this is my personal opinion). It is job deployments. Please take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops).